# React native concatenate instead of sum

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am creating an app using React Native and Firebase. Sample data from firebase is as below.

### Sample Data (Firebase)

```
accountName:"Frimi"
accountType:"debit"
createdAt:March 24, 2020 at 7:05:56 PM UTC+5:30
initialAmount:2000
userId:"t7DJ##################"
username:"de#####"
```

From this data's I need to get the total amount of the initialAmount from several data's. I do this in react native as follows

### Fetch Total (React Native)

```
fetchTotalAmount = () => {
    const { accounts } = this.props
    const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    return accounts && accounts.map((account) => {
        let total = 0
        return account.userId == uid ?
            total += account.initialAmount : null
    })
}
```

The problem here is instead of adding values I am getting concatenated string. I need to get sum of the initialAmount.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting `account.initialAmount` to a Number like:

```
total += Number(account.initialAmount) : null
```

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/convert-a-string-to-an-integer) post for more casting references.

Comment: Still getting concatenated string